How can I add jpg file name in top left corner of each pdf file created with img2pdf?
find . -name 'Vol_*.tif' -print0 | sort -z -V | xargs -0r img2pdf -o out.pdf

CAS wrote above and with this I was able to solve my needs.
One extra feature: For each TIF file I would like to print on the converted PDF file as header or footer the TIF file name.
I write TIF but in my case I have JPG files.
Does anyone know how to do this?
thanks.

what have you investigated so far? Where are you stuck?

With imagemagick, something like mogrify  -font Liberation-Sans -fill white -undercolor '#00000080' -pointsize 26 -gravity South -annotate +10+10 %t 'Vol_*.tif' before?

ImageMagick's magick will do it.
magick test.jpg -pointsize 24 -fill black -draw 'text 10,30 "Top left corner."' test2.jpg

The text 10 is pixels from the left & the 30 is pixels from the top.
Simple as that.

In order to process multiple files I would recommend a small shell script.
#!/bin/bash

find . -name '*.jpg' -print0 | sort -V | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    magick "$file" -pointsize 24 -fill black -draw "text 10,30 '$file'" "text_$file"
    img2pdf "text_$file" -o "${file%.*}.pdf"
done

exit 0

Save as: text2jpg2pdf.sh
Change mode executable: chmod +x text2jpg2pdf.sh
Usage: ./text2jpg2pdf.sh
Run from any directory and it will process all .jpg files accordingly.

10,30 is 10px from left and 30px from top

@MarkSetchell Good call.
